# VLC Unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, vlc

I upgrade from LTS 16.04 to 18.04 from software updater

VLC has been removed and now installing VLC giving the following errors

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

updated

```
apt-cache policy vlc vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-skins2
vlc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     3.0.3-1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
     3.0.1-3build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
     2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
vlc-plugin-qt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     3.0.3-1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
     3.0.1-3build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
vlc-plugin-video-output:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     3.0.3-1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
     3.0.1-3build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
vlc-plugin-skins2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
     4.0.0~rc1~~git20180803+r77246+157~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     3.0.3-1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
     3.0.1-3build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

message from synaptic package when i used the option fix broken packages

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: i have tried package manager but it also giving the error

Comment: Where you got such modern versions of VLC? Ubuntu repositories [have 3.0.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vlc-plugin-qt&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all). Please add output of `apt-cache policy vlc vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-skins2` to the question.

Comment: this is what i get question updated

Comment: question updated again

Comment: sudo apt autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Comment: sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-session-bin libfarstream-0.2-5 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Comment: the first quoted message on my question

Comment: well i think my upgrade installation from 16.04 to 18.04 is corrupted.., i am trying to install another program and it is also giving a same error with different dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You can try to purge [VideoLan PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily?field.series_filter=bionic) and use VLC from official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

For sure install all new dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you have aptitude installed you can try

```
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

Comment: still same issue.,

Comment: question updated with more findings

Comment: You can try to specify exact version of VLC with `sudo apt-get install vlc=3.0.3-1-1ubuntu1`.